# About the locus, when Modulus of a polynomial is 1

Tags: complex-analysis

For a polynomial $P$, when I draw a Mathematica picture for  $\{z\in \mathbb C: |P(z)|=1\}$,  mostly I get circles (topologically).  Does this happen for every polynomial $P$?  Is there any proof for this, or some reference?

Comment: what do you mean by mostly? It is not clear what are you asking, you should add a bit more explanations and to show some pictures, otherwise it can be answered.

Comment: It depends on the number of critical points $P'(w)=0, |P(w)| \le 1$; try to draw $z^2-z$ and then left and right perturbations $z^2-2.1z, z^2-1.9z$

Comment: Meant $|z^-2z|=1$ which is a figure eight due to the critical point at $1$; then for $z$ coefficient higher than $2$, the critical point moves inside so now we get two circles, while of course for values less than $2$ the critical point is outside so we have one circle; same behavior is in general, the locus of $|P(z)|=1$ is a bunch of disjoint Jordan curves (topological circles) as long as there are no critical points there and $P$ behaves like a Blaschke products when composed with appropriate Riemann maps

Comment: @Conrad,  thanks it helps.